# Reparsing a file or unpickling

Tags: python, file, pickle

I have a 100Mb file with roughly 10million lines that I need to parse into a dictionary every time I run my code. This process is incredibly slow, and I am hunting for ways to speed it up. One thought that came to mind is to parse the file once and then use pickle to save it to disk. I'm not sure this would result in a speed up.

Any suggestions appreciated.

EDIT:
After doing some testing, I am worried that the slow down happens when I create the dictionary. Pickling does seem significantly faster, though I wouldn't mind doing better.

Lalit

Comment: That would take several minutes to try. Have you tried?

Comment: Depends on how much parsing work you're doing, and if it's > than the work done by the pickler. You could just be I/O bound. Only one way to find out, and I don't think the Stackoverflowers are going to do it for you :)

Comment: How does each line end up in the dictionary?

Comment: I will run some tests and let people know. Each line is of the form a,b,c,d and I create a dict store, such that store[a] = (b,c,d). Note that a could appear on many different lines.

Comment: Are you using a `for` loop to get data into the `dict`? Reworking that into a list comprehension could make your code significantly faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) has in my experience been much faster for dumping/loading data in python then cPickle, even when using the highest protocol.

However, if you have a dictionary with 10 million entries in it, you might want to check that you're not hitting the upper limit of your computer's memory. The process will happen much slower if you run out of memory and have to use swap.

Comment: He's said that it's a 100 mb file. Not too likely that he's running out of memory.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi The dictionary data structure can actually create quite a bit of memory overhead. A quick test on my end with a 10 million line, 100 mb file with one space separated key and value per line inflates to over a 1Gb of memory. Depending on the what your actually doing, the cost can add up quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you use the data, you could

- divide it into many smaller files and load only what's needed
- create an index into the file and lazy-load
- store it to a database and then query the database

Can you give us a better idea just what your data looks like (structure)?

How you are using the data? Do you actually use every row on every execution? If you only use a subset on each run, could the data be pre-sorted?

Comment: I need every single row on each execution. The data is presorted - and reading it in is still slow.